# Sphinx - ran`make html` and I am missing content for a few modules

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, init

Repo link: https://github.com/Eric-Cortez/aepsych-fork

Problem: I am running into an issue when generating sphinx documentation when I run `make html` most of the modules are generated except for 3 which are aepsych.database, aepsych.plotting, and aepsych.server.

**file structure:**

```
    (root)
    aepsych-fork/
   |__ aepsych/      <--- docs in this dir 
   |__ sphinx/
   |   |__ build/
   |   |__ Makefile
   |   |__ make.bat
   |   |__ source/
   |       |___conf.py
   |       |___index.rst
   | **other files**
```

**conf.py [path]:**

```
    import os
    import sys

    # from pkg_resources import get_distribution

    current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    target_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_dir, 
    "../.."))
    sys.path.insert(0, target_dir)
```

**What I tried:**

I have been able to generate this documentation previously by running `make html`.
example:
https://aepsych.org/api/database.html
But, I tried to rebuild the sphinx docs todays and ran into a an error

```
    WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'acquisition.bvn' 
    from module 'aepsych'; the following exception was raised:
    No module named 'gpytorch'
```

gpytorch is a dependency that is being used within the the aepsych module, but I do not want to generate documentation for the gpytorch module. I did some research and added

```
    autodoc_mock_imports = ["botorch", 'gpytorch', "torch"]
```

to the aepsych-fork/sphinx/conf.py which resolved the missing module error and generated most of the docs accept for the three missing modules. I am having trouble finding the reason that the docs for those files are not being generated as when I run `make html` I don't get any errors in the console.

**Below is the console output:**

```
    Running Sphinx v5.0.2
    making output directory... done
    building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
    building [html]: targets for 16 source files that are out of date
    updating environment: [new config] 16 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
```

I did notice the reading source does not reach 100%. I gets stuck at reading sources... [ 25%] benchmark

does anyone have any suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

I did notice that the `__init__.py` file is empty for the database/ module.

```
    import sys

    from ..config import Config
    from .db import Database


    __all__ = [
      "Database" 
    ]

    Config.register_module(sys.modules[__name__])
```

I added the code above to the `databases/__init__.py` but the docs still did not generate.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The GitHub Actions manifest does indicate many dependencies https://github.com/facebookresearch/aepsych/blob/main/.github/workflows/build-lint-test.yml So, have you installed all of them? It is also strange that they only run the workflow on Mac, so you might ask the authors directly on GitHub https://github.com/facebookresearch/aepsych/issues

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at the issue. I recreated a conda environment with all of the dependencies and was still getting an error.

     WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'acquisition.bvn' from module 
     'aepsych'; the following exception was raised:
      No module named 'botorch.sampling.normal'




So I added `autodoc_mock_imports = ["botorch"]` to sphinx/conf.py and that resolved the issue. I think I may have been missing some dependencies. Thank you for your help! @LexLi

Comment: If you resolved it, you can post and accept your own answer below to close the discussion. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated a conda environment with all of the dependencies and was still getting an error. WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'acquisition.bvn' from module 'aepsych'; the following exception was raised: No module named 'botorch.sampling.normal' So I added autodoc_mock_imports = ["botorch"] to sphinx/conf.py and that resolved the issue. I may have been missing some dependencies.